# Question on class variables in Python vs C++ and Java

Tags: python

Currently learning Python, and going through this block of code below.

My question is such: in C++ and Java, would counter's value have been equal one (instead of 3 like it is here after the code is ran), since in these languages each instance of `ExampleClass` result in the creation of a new counter variable set to 1?  Assume some similarities, such as counter is a private variable, like it is in the Python code block below.

```py
class ExampleClass:
    __counter = 0
    def init(self, val = 1):
        self.__first = val
        ExampleClass.__counter += 1

example_object_1 = ExampleClass()
example_object_2 = ExampleClass(2)
example_object_3 = ExampleClass(4)

print(example_object_1.dict, example_object_1._ExampleClass__counter)
print(example_object_2.dict, example_object_2._ExampleClass__counter)
print(example_object_3.dict, example_object_3._ExampleClass__counter)
```

I felt compelled to ask to know if I'm mis-remembering my C++ and Java, and not understanding a concept fully.

Comment: If counter is static in c++ it would equal 3 otherwise it will be 1.

Comment: Edit code, `__init__(self, val=1)` and parts with `example_object_x.__dict__`

Comment: The same goes for Java, if it were static it would be 3. For instance field, it would be 1 for each.

Comment: `__counter` here is roughly equivalent to a static data member in C++. It belongs to the class, not to individual instances of that class. In contrast, `__first` is similar to a non-static data member.

Comment: Class variables behave basically the same in all of those languages, but the syntax for declaring them is different.  In Python you declare all of your instance variables within the `__init__` method and all the class variables outside of it, whereas in C++/Java all variables are declared outside the constructor and you have to use the `static` keyword to indicate which are class variables instead of instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation.

This is a static variable. In Java and C++, the result would be the same (also 3). Example Java:

```java
public class ExampleClass {
    static int counter = 0;
    public ExampleClass() {
        ExampleClass.counter++;
    }
}
```

One `counter`, value is 3

You could also use an instance variable (like `__first` in your example):

```java
public class ExampleClass {
    int counter = 0;
    public ExampleClass() {
        this.counter++;
    }
}
```

Three `counter`s (one per object), value is 1 for each of them.